# Installing Laravel 5 application on DirectAdmin VPS

Tags: php, laravel, directadmin

I read and tried several methods and none worked. I always get either `400` or `500` error. The app works perfectly on localhost.

What are the **exact** steps in order to get Laravel 5 up and running on a VPS with DirectAdmin CP??

Please don't link to other questions as I read them all. Some don't even work with Laravel 5 anymore.

Note: DirectAdmin sees `public_html` as the document root.

I have SSH root access and Composer is installed.

*VPS Configs: Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 7.0.3.*

Comment: Would you mind providing a reason for that downvote?

Comment: What errors do you see from your apache error log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out DirectAdmin has a section where you can define custom Apache configs (including Document root). So here are the steps:

1- Login to your admin area (as System Admin)

2- From `Extra features` select `Custom Httpd Configurations`

3- Select the domain you want to config

4- In the textarea at the top enter the following:

```
|?DOCROOT=/home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/public|
```

5- Click save. Now wait for a minute or two and voila! It works.

Obviously you need to change the `username` and `example.com` according to your setup.

[Read more about this feature.](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=3)